# Putting the page number as a footer on the page when outputting the html code to word

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, openxml

I tried to write a text in the footer part of the word with the code I wrote below, but it did not even write any text to the output. Actually, what I need is to write the page number as a footer in the word (like Page 1/5.)

```
 FooterPart footerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();
 footerPart.Footer = new Footer();
 footerPart.Footer = new 
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Footer();

 footerPart.Footer.Append
 (new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph
    (new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run
         (new Text("Page Number")))
         {
             ParagraphProperties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.ParagraphProperties()
             {
                  Justification = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Justification()
                  {
                       Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.JustificationValues.Center
                  }
              }
          });

          FooterReference footerReference = new FooterReference { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart) };
          body.Append(new SectionProperties(footerReference));
```

I tried all the solutions on Google, but I could not print any data in the footer part.